# cat one file to multiple file and output multiple files

Tags: cat

I'm trying to cat 1 main-file to multiple single files. The output file should benamed main-file_file1

**For example**

```
main-file + file1 = mailfile_file1

main-file + file2 = mailfile_file2

main-file + file3 = mailfile_file3
.
.
.

main-file + fileN = mainfile_fileN
```

**I guess I could**

```
cat mail-file file1 > mail-file_file1
```

but I have 100 files to cat to mail-file so that won't be so efficient.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need a bash for loop (assuming your shell is bash)! In you case you would do something like this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do cat mail-file file$i > mail-file_file$i; done
```